# How to utilize ConcurrentHashMap.merge() with a shared AtomicInteger

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a shared global counter that I want to check is less than a total before doing a concurrent computation and update into a map. How can I use modern java concurrency utils / API to ensure this is atomic?

```java
class SharedAccess {

    AtomicInteger globalCounter = new AtomicInterger();
    Map<String, Integer> counterPerKey = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()

    class Holder{
        Integer value
    }

    public Holder incrementForKeyMultipleThreads(String key) {
         if (total.get() < 1000) {

          Integer newTotal = counterPerKey.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
          globalCounter.increment();
         return new Holder(newTotal);

    }

  }

}
```

EDIT: This is solved by the merge function actually being atomic too. Therefore you get the benefit of the multiple thread access to the rest of the map, and the atomic inc on the total counter.

```
class SharedAccess {

    AtomicInteger globalCounter = new AtomicInterger();
    Map<String, Integer> counterPerKey = new ConcurrentHashMap<>()

    class Holder{
        Integer value
    }

    public Holder incrementForKeyMultipleThreads(String key) {
         if (total.get() < 1000) {

          Integer newTotal = counterPerKey.merge(key, 1, (v1, v2) -> {
              globalCounter.increment();
              return v1+v1;
          }  

         return new Holder(newTotal);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: What is `total`?

Answer (score 1):

Modern java still uses the same basic principles of thread-safety. You have a *check-then-act* scenario, which covers pretty much the whole method. So you can make the method `synchronized`:

```
public synchronized Holder incrementForKeyMultipleThreads(String key) {
    if (globalCounter.get() < 1000) {
        globalCounter.increment();
        return new Holder(counterPerKey.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum));
    }
    return null;
}
```

And then if this is the only place you are using (reading or writing) `globalCounter`, you can change it to `int`.

Comment: Using `synchronized` is flies in the face of compare-and-set used by the `AtomicInteger` and `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar you can make changes to both of them atomic individually, but how would you make changes to both of those objects in a single atomic operation? Keen to learn if you post your answer.

Comment: Bit late to the game replying to this, but i found out that the merge function is infact atomic in the CHM.